# Does defragmentation increase lifespan of hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, defragment

I would like to ask you if defragmentation actually increase lifespan of hard disk drive, or is it just performance thing?

Another point of view, can defragmentation degrade lifespan of hard disk drive? Let's say that I was defragmenting 2TB hard disk drive like 2 days, so it means that my HDD was 2 days constantly reading and writing data, so I think it could do some wear to hard disk drive?

Answer (score 2):

Every use and head movement is putting load onto your drive.
This applies to defragmentation itself.
Another factor is the defragmentation strategy.

You pay when your drive is being defragmented and you earn when using the drive as user tomsk described profiting from less head movement for instance.

It makes a difference if defragmentation tries to produce contiguous files or if defragmentation tries to fill all empty clusters in between. The latter is more expensive in defragmentation time and head movements.

The net effect is difficult to judge as you might want to log head movements.
This is not a SMART attribute yet.